# neo4j cypher - divide results from two grouped queries (column 1 / column 2)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have a graph that relates students to their assessments.

```
(:student)-[:assessed_on]->(:assessment)
```

The assessment nodes contain properties that tell me about how a student performed on that assessment. For example,

```
math_score: 50
```

The student nodes contain properties that tells me which school the student attends. For example,

```
school_name: 'school_of_rock'
```

Suppose I wanted to return the proportion of students from each school that scored above 50.

To get the numerator I can use this query:

```
MATCH (s:student)-[:assessed_on]->(a:assessment)
WHERE a.math_score>50
RETURN s.school_name as school, count(a) as numerator
ORDER BY school

school              numerator:
------              ---------
school_of_rock       24
school_of_jazz       40
school_of_country    12
```

To get the denominator I can do the same but take out the WHERE clause to get the total, returning:

```
school              denominator:
------              ---------
school_of_rock       48
school_of_jazz       50
school_of_country    48
```

But what I'm looking for in one query is the following result (which is just numerator/denominator):

```
school              result:
------              ---------
school_of_rock       .5
school_of_jazz       .8
school_of_country    .25
```

I have tried this:

```
MATCH (s:student)-[:assessed_with]->(a:assessment)
WHERE a.math_score>50
WITH s.school_name as school, count(a) as numerator
MATCH (s:student)-[:assessed_with]->(a:assessment)
RETURN school, numerator/count(a) as proportion_above_50
```

But the numerator is not correct when I combine the queries so I'm obviously doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cypher` is very similar to the natural language. So you say: count me the total number of nodes; then choose from them necessary for me; then the number of needed divided by total. For example:

```
MATCH (s:student)-[:assessed_on]->(a:assessment)
WITH s.school_name as school, 
     collect(a) as allNodes
WITH school, 
     size(FILTER(a in allNodes WHERE a.math_score > 0.5)) as top,
     size(allNodes)*1.0 as bottom
RETURN school, 
       top/bottom as proportion_above_50
ORDER BY school
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Fantastic. Thank you very much.

Comment: For future readers of this solution, it is worth noting that future versions of Neo4j will replace `FILTER(...)` with `[...]`.  But it works great for now!